# Ajax Content Replacement with history url change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a fully functional Ajax Content Replacement script. The problem is that it adds forwards like /about or /work or /contact to the adress but when I reload the site, the file cannot be find. Why?

Someone told me that the problem is that I added the file manually. How does that work? I am not a Javascript expert but I would like to learn it.

Somehow I need to add the history (via history api?). My .html files are in data. The strange thing is that it finds the file but when I try to find it manually, I get 404 Error or when I refresh the site with F5.

Can you help me and show me how it works. We can use my code to find the error. Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE:** [Website Link](http://celebrateyou.eu/)

**Html**

```
<a class="hovers" href="about">About</a>
<a class="hovers" href="projects">Projects</a>
<a class="hovers" href="services">Services</a>
<a class="hovers" href="contact">Contact</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#allcontent').load('data/home.html');
    $('.hovers').click(function () {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#allcontent').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(this).animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 0);
            $(this).hide().load('data/' + page).fadeIn('normal');
        });
    });
});

$('.hovers').click(function () {
    history.pushState({
        path: this.path
    }, '', this.href)
    $.get(this.href, function (data) {
        $('#allcontent').slideTo(data)
    })
    return false
})

$(window).bind('popstate', function () {
    $('#allcontent').slideTo(location.pathname)
})
```

Comment: I guess that, since you got this line: $('#allcontent').load('data/home.html'); each time the page is being loaded or refrshed, your script will load 'data/home.html'. You will have to add something like '#about' to your url and then check for a 'about', 'projects'... in the url with your javascript before loading home.html.

Comment: Since you *are* getting data from that URI via `$.get`, I can't see why it would 404 when you hit it directly.

Comment: I dont know but I became this 404 error :/

Comment: By the way, shouldn't it be "$(this).hide().load('data/' + page+'.html')"?

Comment: oh yes thats right :) But it doesn't fix my main problem

Comment: @Quentin with directly I mean to type this adress into my urlfield not to click on ".hovers"

Comment: @martin85 — Yes, that is what I meant too.

Comment: How does your URL look like, when you hit F5 an get that 404 error?

Comment: @Quentin oh okey. But why it's not working?

Comment: @bouscher for example http://domain.com/home

Comment: Please use `example.com` for example URIs. `domain.com` is a real site.

Comment: Do all your HTML pages include this javascript?

Comment: @ Reinder No only the index.html

Comment: @martin85 So your server will most probably look for a folder 'home' and an index file there, both don't exist. Maybe you should look into jquery address (http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/)

Comment: @bouscher and how does it work with my existing code?

Answer (score 0):

> I made a fully functional Ajax Content Replacement script. The problem is that it adds forwards like /about or /work or /contact to the adress but when I reload the site, the file cannot be find. Why?

Your code is effectively saying two things:

- Load some data from this URL and add it to the page.
- Tell the browser that the modifications to the current page make it the same as some other page at some other URL.

You have to create the page at that the other URL yourself.

You haven't done anything on your server to tell it to respond to `/about` (and its friends) with anything other than a 404 error.

You have to create `/about` yourself. `pushState` won't do it for you.

Comment: now i become a 403 error that said i don't have permission to access /about/ on this server.

Comment: Which is still a problem with your server and not with any of the code you've provided in the question. I've no idea what you've done to try to create `/about` (i.e. what has changed it from 404 to 403), and you haven't told us why it is a forbidden a URI (file permissions? authentication requirement? something that the server logs might explain if you look at them?)

Comment: no the file permissions are ok also the authentication requirement! i've created a folder named /about/ in the main directory not in the /data/ folder with the about.html file.

Comment: Sounds like you have turned directory listings off and not put an index file in the directory.

Comment: when i put an index file in the directory the page will be found but white :D because i ONLY replace the "#allcontent" not a full page

Comment: Yes, as I said, you have to deliver the complete page from the server that you are currently only building with client side JavaScript.

Comment: i build now a example page and open a new Question. Maybe it's easier to understand to solve it.

Comment: Don't open a new question. The problem is simple. Look at the second bullet point in the answer. See what you are telling the browser? You just have to make what you are telling the browser true.

Comment: Wait a second i will send a url adress to the website link :)

Comment: Why? I've told you what you need to do to fix it.

Comment: Here is the link: http://celebrateyou.eu/ I haven't told the browser nothing because I have no Idea what i have to tell him. Its my very first time with ajax. i simply want that the browser finds my data located in data/about.html

Comment: You've told the browser plenty (the code is in your question, and an English translation of it is in my answer (as bullet points)).

Comment: If you want the browser to find that data, then you need to place a page at `/about` which fetches that data (using server side code, otherwise there is no point in using `pushState`) and provides a complete HTML document.

Comment: I've told the browser that what i think to solve the problem. But you see it doesn't solve it ;) My english is not so good, i know but I shall do my best.

Comment: but when i provides a complete html the ajax is waste. I want that the content replace from "allcontent" is still there.

Comment: and how i do this that a page fetches at /about that data?

Comment: It isn't a waste, because after the initial page is loaded, Ajax can be used to load just the data from the server and give better performance to the client. (Implementing a robust Ajax solution (which has to use  [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)) is *more work for the developer*, but the point of Ajax is to make things faster for the consumer not the developer).

Comment: Pick your favourite server side language and template library. Use them.

Comment: hm thank you so much Quentin for your time and help! But i'm searching now for a freelance developer who can fix it because i cant solve it by myself :)